# Form duplications

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a tough time figuring out how to write an if function in my code.  I am trying to prevent my PHP form from allowing duplicates being submitted to my MySQL database.  I am wanting to prevent a submission based on the email address being inputted into my form.  Can someone guide me in the right direction?  Thanks.

```
<?php
  $dbc = mysqli_connect('n/a', 'n/a', 'n/a', 'n/a')
    or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

  $store_name = $_POST['storename'];
  $full_name = $_POST['fullname'];
  $address = $_POST['address'];
  $city = $_POST['city'];
  $state = $_POST['state'];
  $zip = $_POST['zip'];
  $phone = $_POST['phone'];
  $fax = $_POST['fax'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $url = $_POST['url'];

  $query = "INSERT INTO store_location (store_name, full_name, address, city, state, zip,     phone, fax, email, url)  VALUES ('$store_name', '$full_name', '$address', '$city',     '$state', '$zip', '$phone', '$fax', '$email', '$url')";
  mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
or die('Error querying database.');

  echo 'New TeachPro store added.';
   echo '<br/><br/>';

  mysqli_close($dbc);
    ?>
```

Comment: Do a select first with the entered email address - if it returns 0 results then insert else display a duplicate message ....

Comment: You can make whole record in database unique

Comment: your code is vulnerable to sql injection ..

Comment: While you're using mysqli, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection! Read about prepared statements in the context of mysqli.

Comment: two things: Validate the data first. Always sanitize data before saving it to your db, or there maybe sql injection

Comment: @ManseUK No need to send two queries, if the column is unique the insert/update statements will fail. You could also use an `INSERT INTO … ON DUPLICATE KEY …` query to enable updating on errors.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a unique key on the email column on your database table. Now, if you try to insert the same email address twice, the MySQL responds with an according error message. You may catch those error message and present a useful error message text to the user.

I used that approach for checking usernames:

```
try
{
    /** @var $userInsertUpdateStmt PDOStatement */

    $userInsertUpdateStmt->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    if($e->errorInfo[1] == 1062)
    {
        /* username already used */
        return User::ERR_USERNAME_ASSIGNED;
    }
    return User::ERR_SQL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(*) FORM ... WHERE store_name = ... OR full_name=...
```

If you have 0 rows as a result of this query, you're good to go.

Also, your query is vulnerable to SQL-injection (google that).